# How to generate csv report simultaneously for every thread request while running load test from non gui mode

Tags: jmeter

Jmeter  generates report only after the script completes or stopped.
Is there a way to generate report simultaneously for every thread request while executing load test from command line?

Answer (score 1):

JMeter periodically writes metrics into the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles)

If you want to enable real-time storing of the metrics so they would appear in the .jtl file as soon as the request is finished you can add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=true
```

More information:

- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Results file configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)

Alternative option would be using [Backend Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Backend_Listener) to store the metrics in InfluxDB and visalizing them in Grafana, see [Real-time results](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html) User Manual chapter for more information. Backend Listener stores not all the metrics, but rather aggregated ones however this might be sufficient for your needs.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri . Added jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=true in user.properties file and run this command 
 jmeter -n -t .\sample.jmx -l report.jtl  -e -o .\html\ . But the jtl file is not updating after each request. It updates only after script completes or if i press ctrl+c

Comment: also tried jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=true -n -t .\sample.jmx -l report.jtl -e -o .\html\ . , but not getting real time results

Comment: Thanks Dimitri uncommenting jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=true in jmeter.properties file generated real time metrics in jtl file